# How to get values from Menubutton the element as a checkbutton

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I am attempting to create a checkbox list using Tkinter in python.
I added all components and button
but i dint know how to retrieve the values from the components. I want to retrieve the values such as: Sun, Mon... that will be checked and save it in the list after enter the button.
the code below reflects what I am attempting to describe:

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="CheckComboBox", relief=RAISED )
mb.grid()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu
Item1 = StringVar()
Item2 = StringVar()
Item3 = StringVar()
Item4 = StringVar()
Item5 = StringVar()

lst = []

def get_checked(inputuser):
    for item in [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5]:
        if item.get()== '1':
            lst.append(inputuser)
    # do something with lst

mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Sun", variable=Item1, command=get_checked("Sun"))
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Mon", variable=Item2, command=get_checked("Mon"))
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Teu", variable=Item3, command=get_checked("Teu"))
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Wed", variable=Item4, command=get_checked("Wed"))
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Fri", variable=Item5, command=get_checked("Fri"))


def getresposees():   
    print(lst)
    
Button22= Button(top, text='Ok',  fg= 'white', command=getresposees , bg='gray', width=15) 
Button22.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a command parameter to the `add_checkbutton` calls that points to a callback function that gets the state of each of the `StringVar()` items.  The callback will then be executed each time one of the menu options is selected or deselected.

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="CheckComboBox", relief=RAISED )
mb.pack()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu
Item1 = StringVar()
Item2 = StringVar()
Item3 = StringVar()
Item4 = StringVar()
Item5 = StringVar()

def get_checked():
    lst = []
    for item in [Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5]:
        lst.append(item.get())
    print(lst)
    # do something with lst

mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Sun", variable=Item1, command=get_checked)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Mon", variable=Item2, command=get_checked)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Teu", variable=Item3, command=get_checked)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Wed", variable=Item4, command=get_checked)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="Fri", variable=Item5, command=get_checked)

    
Button22= Button(top, text='Ok',  fg= 'white', command=get_checked , bg='gray', width=15) 
Button22.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

---

Below is and example that makes the callback work with the button only and only print the menu items that are selected.

```
from tkinter import *
top = Tk()
mb=  Menubutton ( top, text="CheckComboBox", relief=RAISED )
mb.pack()
mb.menu  =  Menu ( mb, tearoff = 0 )
mb["menu"]  =  mb.menu
Item1 = StringVar()
Item2 = StringVar()
Item3 = StringVar()
Item4 = StringVar()
Item5 = StringVar()

def get_checked():
    values = ["Sun", "Mon", "Teu", "Wed", "Fri"]
    lst = []
    for i, item in enumerate([Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5]):
        if item.get() == "1":
            lst.append(values[i])
    print(lst)
    # do something with lst

mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Sun", variable=Item1)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Mon", variable=Item2)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Teu", variable=Item3)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Wed", variable=Item4)
mb.menu.add_checkbutton(label="Fri", variable=Item5)

    
Button22= Button(top, text='Ok',  fg= 'white', command=get_checked , bg='gray', width=15) 
Button22.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

Comment: def get_checked():
    values = ["Sun", "Mon", "Teu", "Wed", "Fri"]
    lst = [values[i] for (i, item) in enumerate([Item1, Item2, Item3, Item4, Item5])if item.get() == "1"]             
    print(lst)

Comment: @toyotaSupra  I intentionally made the callback simple and verbose.  The OP's experience level is limited and I wanted to make sure it was easy to understand.